# AttributeError: module 'quizbot.quiz.models' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, database, attributeerror

Trying to figure out why I am getting this error and how to fix it. Trying to use django
import-export library for importing files into the database.

I have no idea what to try but have looked it up with nothing to give. I used the django-import
-export documentation but did not help solve this issue.

```
from django.db import models


# from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _


# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    # For Translation
    # title = models.CharField(_(""), max_length=255)
    # JUST PUT _ before any " " areas

    objects = None
    LEVEL = (
        (0, ('Any')),
        (1, ('Beginner')),
        (2, ('Intermediate')),
        (3, ('Advanced')),
        (4, ('Expert')),
    )

    # sets the amount of chars for the max length
    title = models.CharField(("title"), max_length=255)
    # This is used to make the points system
    points = models.SmallIntegerField("points")
    # This is used to make the difficulty settings
    difficulty = models.IntegerField(('Difficulty'), choices=LEVEL, default=0)
    # This question is shown be default
    is_active = models.BooleanField(("Is Active"), default=True)
    # When the question was created
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(("Created"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    # When the question was last updated
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(("Updated"), auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Answer(models.Model):
    # the first field in ForeignKey is identifying the table we want
    ### This line is where the delete module is ###
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name="answer", verbose_name=("Question"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(("Answer"), max_length=255)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(("Correct Answer"), default=False)
    # This question is shown be default
    is_active = models.BooleanField(("Is Active"), default=True)
    # When the question was created
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(("Created"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    # When the question was last updated
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(("Updated"), auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

models.py ^

```
from django.contrib import admin
# From IMPORT EXPORT DJANGO
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources
# Register your models here.
# from all the files import
from . import models
class QuizResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = models

class DBQuizAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = QuizResource
admin.site.reqister(models, DBQuizAdmin)
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'quizbot.quiz.models' has no attribute '_meta'
Is the error message

Comment: What is the quiz resource supposed to serialize? It should have a model, not a module of models.

Comment: I can not remember what I did but I was able to get it to work.